# Org mode tag inheritance in agenda custom commands

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, tags, sparse-tree

I want to create Org Mode agenda views or sparse trees with tag inheritance disabled so that tagged headlines are included but children are not. I do not want to turn off tag inheritance globally. I thought this could be accomplished by [setting options for custom commands,](https://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-options.html#Setting-options) as in the following example:

```
 (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("y" tags "tag1|tag2"
       ((org-agenda-use-tag-inheritance nil)))))
```

However, the resulting agenda view includes all children of the tagged headlines. The desired result can be achieved by disabling tag inheritance globally, `(setq org-use-tag-inheritance nil)`, but I do not want to disable tag inheritance globally, only for the agenda custom command.

Alternatively I have tried to create the same filter using a sparse tree:

```
   (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("Y" tags-tree "tag1|tag2"
      ((org-show-context-detail 'minimal)))))
```

But this returns a sparse tree including all children and ancestors of the tagged headlines. Again, if I disable tag inheritance globally I achieve the desired result. What am I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The docstring of `org-agenda-use-tag-inheritance` says that:

> In tags/tags-todo/tags-tree agenda views, tag inheritance is
> controlled by `org-use-tag-inheritance`.

Both of these work as expected even when `org-use-tag-inheritance` is non-nil globally:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("y" tags "tag1|tag2"
         ((org-use-tag-inheritance nil)))))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("Y" tags-tree "tag1|tag2"
         ((org-use-tag-inheritance nil)))))
```

Comment: I see you're setting this in code above, but do you have recommendations for how to use the Customize UI for Org Agenda Custom Commands? I am trying to use a local setting > "any variable" > and then `org-use-tag-inheritance` as nil, but I don't see the changes taking effect.

Comment: Disregard, forgot to quote the value. For others, this works if you set this variable within the Customize UI with a "any variable" local setting as `'org-use-tag-inheritance` set to `nil`